# Difference between monoidal and tensor categories

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories, monoidal-categories, additive-categories

Is a monoidal category just another word for tensor category or are those two different (but still similiar) things in the sense that one of them is more general?

Are those categories supposed to be additive (or even abelian)? Is maybe this the difference between the deffinitions?

Comment: I believe that they are the same thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Monoidal category" always means a category with a monoidal structure, and that's it. Some authors use "tensor category" to mean a monoidal category possibly with some extra axioms which differ depending on the author; see the [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/tensor+category) for some possible examples. The longest list of axioms I know is in Etingof's [book](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/egnobookfinal.pdf): here a **tensor category** is a monoidal category which

- is abelian
- is enriched over $k$-vector spaces for $k$ an algebraically closed field, such that $\otimes$ is $k$-bilinear
- is rigid (every object has a left and right dual)
- is locally finite (every Hom is finite-dimensional and every object has finite length, meaning is a finite iterated extension of simple objects)
- satisfies $\text{End}(1) \cong k$.

These are very close to fusion categories except that they aren't required to be semisimple, and are much less general than monoidal categories.